# Thread.Sleep(Int32) does not work C#

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Fuzzy.Test.DateTimeParserTests
{
    class TimeValidationTests
    {
        DateTime first = SayusiAndo.Tools.QA.BDD.Specflow.Fuzzy.Fuzzy.Parse("next week", DateTime.Now);
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Gives me the error: 
`Error 1 Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`
 and `Error 2   'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.TimeSpan)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'`

I am using System.Threading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first error sounds like you have an extra '(' before this statement in the code.

Comment: Are you making sure to use it inside a class?  That seems like the error you get when you put it inside the namespace but outside the class.

Comment: You will need to post more code for us to help.

Comment: There's no context for us to go on.  A single function call does not make a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the code to show the whole class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main points:

### Scoping

From your problem perspective, you are calling it from an invalid scope. You cannot call methods from the class scope. In this case, you have to define a scope (like a Method for sample) to make this code works and call it. [Read more about scoping in .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

### Sleep

The [`System.Threading.Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) class has an static method called [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx). This method has two overloads. The [first one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) has an argument where an `int` is taken as milliseconds. The [second one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/274eh01d(v=vs.110).aspx) accept an `TimeSpan`. See the samples:

```
// for 100 milliseconds
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

// for 5 seconds (using TimeSpan)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

// for 1 minute  (using TimeSpan)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

From MSDN documentation about Thread.Sleep method:

> Blocks the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.

### Conclusion

Try a code like this:

```
class TimeValidationTests
{
  public void Interval()
  {
     // some code...
     Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

And instance it

```
TimeValidationTests t = new TimeValidationTests();
t.Interval();
```

Comment: You missed the bigger problem that he called Sleep ouside of a function.

Answer (score 3):

`Sleep()` is a `Static` method in `Thread` class and not a Instance method. The way you are calling it is not valid through an instance like

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.sleep(100);
```

It should be like below through the class name since it's a static member

```
Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Also, per your posted code calling of `Sleep` method is as if it's a class member for your class `TimeValidationTests` as pointed by @Scott Chamberlian; which is totally wrong.

You should be calling it inside a method body.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Yes absolutely. Edited answer to note that. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be inside a method.

```
class TimeValidationTests
{
  public void NextWeek()
  {
     DateTime first = SayusiAndo.Tools.QA.BDD.Specflow.Fuzzy.Fuzzy.Parse("next week", DateTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thread has no instance method `.Sleep(` it should be `Thread.Sleep` not `t.Sleep`